# Make .NET SqlConnection NOT use Windows session credentials

Tags: c#, .net, sqlconnection

For some reason my .NET (C#) SqlConnection uses my Windows session credentials instead of the specified ones. Is there a way to ignore my session credentials and use the ones I specified?

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=user;" +
                                   "password=pass;server=10.0.10.99;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=databasename; " +
                                   "connection timeout=5");
myConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `Trusted_Connection=yes;` which indicates that integrated security is used and which leads to your Windows credentials getting used.

For a quick reference on connection strings attributes you can take a look at:

[The Connection String Reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Ahh, I just thought of that before reading your post. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: +1 exactly - if you happen to specify *both* `Trusted_Connection` **and** explicit user id/pwd, the trusted connection will prevail